# asadmin enable-secure-admin throws NCLS-ADMIN-00010

Tags: java-8, ubuntu-server, glassfish-5

Trying to `enable-secure-admin` but keep getting the following errors:

```
Command create-domain executed successfully. 

root@ip-123456:/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/bin# asadmin start-domain mydomain 

Waiting for mydomain to start ....... 

Successfully started the domain : mydomain domain  

Location: /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/mydomain 

Log File: /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/mydomain/logs/server.log 

Admin Port: 4848 Command start-domain executed successfully. 

root@ip-123456:/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/bin# asadmin enable-secure-admin 

Enter admin user name>  ocfs 

Enter admin password for user "ocfs"> You must restart all running servers for the change in secure admin to take effect. 

Command enable-secure-admin executed successfully. 

root@ip-123456:/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/bin# asadmin restart-domain mydomain 

NCLS-ADMIN-00010 
NCLS-ADMIN-00010 
NCLS-ADMIN-00010 
NCLS-ADMIN-00010 
NCLS-ADMIN-00010 

.. this goes on forever
```

FYI:

```
root@ip-123456:/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/bin# java -version

java version "1.8.0_181"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```